# Oracle - How to select records based on below logic?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have:

```
 Table A
 -------
 N0       Date        Time
 -----------------------------
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:05
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:06
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:01
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:02

 Table B
 -------
 N0       Date        Time
 -----------------------------
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:02
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:04
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:05
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:07
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:08
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:04
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:05
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:02
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:03
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:00
```

### Desired Result

```
 A.N0     A.Date       A.Time     B.Time
 ----------------------------------------
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:05  10:00:07   
 123    20-Apr-11      10:00:06  10:00:08
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:01  10:00:03
 456    20-Apr-11      10:00:02  10:00:04
```

### Note

If you see above results there are `B.time` should be greater than `A.time` and should not repeat in join.

Please suggest me how to do this with oracle SQL statement.

Comment: Why does the second row have `10:00:08` for its end time and not `10:00:07`?

Comment: Hi,Because 10:00:07 is already selected in first row.

Comment: @hansa - Rows are unordered. The second row doesn't "know" the "first" row chose that time. From a set based perspective, both `10:00:05` and `10:00:06` can match to `10:00:07` and `10:00:08`.

Comment: And why A.time `10:00:01` does not match with B.time `10:00:02` ?

Comment: @ypercube Each B.Time must appear at most once, apparently

Comment: Does your data set guarantee that there will always be a `B.time` which meets the specified rules for every `A.time`?  If not, what do you want to happen?

Comment: is it where b.time = a.time + 2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will give you the output you requested:

```
With NumberedA As
    (
    Select *
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By N0, Date Order By Time ) Num
    From TableA
    )
    , NumberedB As
    (
    Select A.N0, A.Date
        , A.Time ATime
        , B.Time BTime
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By A.N0, A.Date, A.Time Order By B.Time ) Num
    From TableA A
        Join TableB B
            On B.N0 = A.N0
                And B.Date = A.Date
                And B.Time > A.Time
    )
Select A.N0, A.Date, A.Time, B.Time
From NumberedA A
    Join NumberedB B
        On B.N0 = A.N0
            And B.Date = A.Date
            And B.ATime = A.Time
            And B.Num = A.Num
```

That said, it would help if we understood the reasoning behind your request.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

But required to create one new column called 'Flag' in Table B

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_test
IS
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT   *
                 FROM a
             ORDER BY NAME, date, time)
   LOOP
      FOR j IN (SELECT   *
                    FROM b
                ORDER BY NAME, date, time)
      LOOP
         IF     i.NAME = j.NAME
            AND i.date = j.date
            AND j.flag IS NULL
            AND i.time < j.time
         THEN
            INSERT INTO target
                        (NAME, date, time1, time2
                        )
                 VALUES (i.NAME, i.date, i.time, j.time
                        );

            UPDATE b
               SET flag = 'Y'
             WHERE NAME = i.NAME AND date = i.date AND time = j.time;

            COMMIT;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It is working fine....